# How do you consolidate inherited investment accounts?

Tags: investing

Our parents left us stocks and cash in different funds including 5 different Janney accounts and 3 fidelity accounts. Some of the accounts are in my mother's name and others in my father's. Is it a good idea to consolidate all  the Janney accounts into one and all the fidelity accounts into one?

Comment: In who's name would they be put?  IOW, no, I would not consolidate them before being partitioned among the children.  **You** can consolidate during the partition.  (This is just my opinion.  There should be a cited answer.)

Comment: Location might help, but even more important are any of these retirement accounts?

Comment: They obviously are not as the parents are dead. Which means that after paying inheritance tax on the valuation of time of death, they are NORMAL accounts with no cap gains tax owed based on the value taxed in the inheritance.

Comment: If it is the US and one of those accounts is an IRA, then when it is inherited the person has to follow specific rules about RMDs, and may not roll the funds into their own IRA or com-mingle the funds with their own IRA.

Answer (score 2):

If it's an IRA with RMD restrictions then you'll have to follow distribution guidelines, if any, for those accounts.

For unrestricted accounts, the answer might depend on who the executor of the estate is, if he is being paid for his time, how many beneficiaries there are, and how  much time and effort does it take to combine accounts.

Keeping it simple, if there are only two children and all of the accounts are cash, combine them all at the respective brokers and when the estate is settled (probate or a trust), each child will receive a check.  If equities then it's going to involved account transfers.  If there are more than two children and the accounts are a mix of equities and cash, dividing things up becomes even more complicated.

I have one sibling.  When I settled my surviving parent's modest estate, I asked him if he wanted cash plus  half the securities or just cash.  He chose cash and with his approval, I sold half the shares and added that to his half of the estate's cash.  I closed one account at a time and sent him the proceeds until he received his due course.  At the same time, I either retitled or transferred the accounts containing equity to my name.  This was the path of least resistance for me rather than cutting two checks from each account until completion, or cutting two checks for the cash and moving the equities, or any other combination of the two.

The short answer?  It depends on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a good idea.

Remember that any special status is gone - those are not retirement accounts anymore. There are also no profits/losses there anymore that would trigger a tax event - because you tally up the value and pay the inheritance tax and that value is the 0 line for any cap gain.

i.e. if your parents bought stock for 1000 USD that has a current value at time of death of 100k, the inheritance situation has to pay the tax and resets your profit calculation to 100k, you do NOT pay cap gains based on the 1000USD that the stock originally did cost when paying.

So, it is NOW purely a situation of organization, while before legal scenarios may have kept in (i.e. keeping 2 people's accounts separate). So, you can consolidate them. Obviously you may want to keep funds under the guarantee limit in case the holding bank gets into problems. Unless your portfolios are extraordinarily large, what is to be gained by NOT consolidating?

Comment: "those are not retirement accounts anymore" -- this is at best an oversimplification. If they were retirement accounts, they [do not immediately](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/082515/inherited-ira-and-401k-rules-explained.asp) turn into regular taxable accounts. Some accelerated withdrawal schedule may be mandated, so they are not equivalent to one's own retirement accounts, but they still carry some retirement account attributes.

Comment: Its also worth noting there may be explicit instruction in the will leaving particular accounts to people. Which can complicate things...